# NoMethodError in Main#index undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Пытаюсь отобразить список всех пользователей, но выдаёт ошибку.

Вот мой UserController:

[image: UserController]

application.html.erb:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, не используйте скриншоты, пишите ваш код буквами. Именно из-за этого ваш вопрос заминусован

Comment: Понял. Буду знать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переменную `@users` вы определяете в действии `index` в `UsersController`. Это значит, что автоматически она будет доступна во `views/users/index`.

Вы же пытаетесь использовать её в лэйауте `application`, там она не определена и равна `nil`, отсюда и ошибка.

То, что находится в `application.html.erb`, будет отображено на каждой странице вашего приложения. Если вы действительно хотите видеть список пользователей на каждой странице, то вам нужно определять его в `ApplicationController`

```
#application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_users

  private

  def set_users
    @users = User.all
  end
end
```

Если же вы хотите отображать список пользователей на странице `/users`, то переместите ваш код из лэйаута `application` во `views/users/index`.

В любом случае, перечитайте ещё раз внимательно в документации [главу про рендеринг](http://rusrails.ru/layouts-and-rendering-in-rails)

Comment: Спасибо большое!